# Different Outputs Between Intellij and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have created a code that would help me observe how exception handling works. I typed it all through Intellij IDEA, but it is not outputting in the way I wanted it to. The code looks like this:

```
public class JVMException {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        faultyMethod();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
        //prints 1st
        e.printStackTrace();
        fixMemoryLeak();
    }
}

public static void faultyMethod(){
    throw new OutOfMemoryError("JVM is out of memory! Fix memory leak!");
}

public static void fixMemoryLeak(){
    //prints 2nd
    System.out.println("Fixing memory leak...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // prints 3rd
        System.out.println("Done! The memory leak is fixed!");
    }
}}
```

The output should print in the ordered that they were labeled, but I get this result instead:

[ConsoleOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRAh0.png)

When I run the same code in either Eclipse or browser IDEs like Repl.it, it prints out in the correct order. Is there some configuration in Intellij that I have to modify in order to get the correct output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app runs via Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA and stderr/stdout are not synchronized (probably a limitation of Gradle output logging in the IDE console).

The workaround would be to run the app directly using IDE (without Gradle) by setting the "**Build and run using:**" option to `IntelliJ IDEA`:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA]

In addition to that IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3+ versions [have a setting](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016#focus=Comments-27-3733711.0-0) to sync stderr and stdout streams that you can use with Application run configuration:

> Since the next 2019.3 EAP stdout and stderr process streams will
> influence less each other. In particular, streams shouldn't be mixed
> in middle of the lines anymore. For example, running `Test` class
> (from the issue description) won't produce lines like `41 out41 err`.
> Please note that proper ordering between stdout and stderr is still
> not guaranteed by default, but there is a way to enforce it with
> `run.processes.with.redirectedErrorStream` registry key. To enable it,
> do the following:
>
> - "Help | Find Action..." on the main menu; find "Registry..." item and open it;
> - Enable `run.processes.with.redirectedErrorStream` key.
>
> Enabling it will merge stdout and stderr streams of processes spawned
> by IDE. This will ensure proper ordering of messages from
> stdout/stderr. For example, with the registry key enabled, running the
> `Test` class will produce the expected output.
>
> However, as a price, merging stdout and stderr will make them
> indistinguishable: error output will be printed as normal text. Use
> ANSI coloring to highlight error output differently. Please note that
> the registry key is supported for requested run/debug configurations
> only. If it is not supported for your run/debug configuration, please
> submit a request in issue tracker.