# How to make Java Error line keep in its supposes line instead of having it in the bottom or the top of the output

Tags: java, intellij-idea

when I try to use System.err.println() command, its always shows the error code in the bottom or the top of the terminal output instead of having it in its supposed line

[image: Expectation]

[image: Reality]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdout (out) and Stderr (err) output streams are not synchronized by design. The special handling is required to make the output from two different streams synchronous.

Please [see the corresponding issue in IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016).

As a result of fixing this issue, a Registry option was provided to synchronize these streams. The drawback is that IDE will no longer show `err` output in red as the output from these two streams will be merged.

To activate this option use Help | Find Action, type Registry, then find and enable `run.processes.with.redirectedErrorStream` option.

You can [find more details in this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70016#focus=Comments-27-3733711.0-0).

See also my [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64249340/104891).

Unfortunately, it was broken again in 2020.* releases after the Run Targets were introduced. We've [submitted and fixed a corresponding bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-282942). The fix should be available in one of the next updates. If this functionality is critical for you, you can use 2019 release from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html until the fix is released.

Comment: I already enabled it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I mean, the error line is still red, and the code is still spilling everywhere